# if Else php need explanation

Tags: php

i write a code in **php** and i found that there is a problem in a code like this :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['f'])) { ?>
    <?php if($_GET['f']=="message_reçus") { ?>
        -- another code here --
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>  
<?php else { ?>
```

But when i just write it this way :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['f'])) { ?>
    <?php if($_GET['f']=="message_reçus") { ?>
        -- another code here --
    <?php } ?>  
<?php } else { ?>
```

It works.

I need a clear explanation about what caused the problem in the first version because i still convinced that both version are syntactically right!

PHP Parser shows me : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

I don't need any alternative solution i just wonder to know why there is a problem in the first version and what's wrong with it!

Comment: Please fix the uninformative title.

Comment: For things like that use Alternative Syntax - it's easier to read. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: "There is a problem" ?????

Comment: yes! it's really strange.
The Php Parser shows me :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Comment: Put that detail _in the question_ please.

Answer (score 12):

One way to think about it is to replace `?> ... <?php` with `echo "...";`

So your code becomes:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['f'])) {
    echo "\n\t";
    if($_GET['f'] == "message_reçus") {
        echo "\n\t\t";
        // more code here
        echo "\n\t";
    }
}
echo "\n"; // problem!
else {
    // ...
}
```

Whereas if you just have `} else {` you don't have that extra `echo "\n";` in the way.

Comment: This is an interesting analogy but it seems to be nothing more than that: an analogy.

Comment: I don't know what a more technical answer would look like, mind you. Screw it, this'll do!

Comment: `<?php } ?> ` will not print "\n".

Comment: @CooPer Details may vary - iirc `?>\n` does not output that trailing newline, but even then you'd still have `echo "";` (empty string) buggering up the if/else pair.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's true, we can imagine `?><?php` as a command, not echoing something. you should edit your post because i cant undo downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The description to the problem was detailed in a different answer by @NietTheDarkAbsol. I'm adding this answer to add an alternative solution to the problem by removing it.

#### The problem exlained (@NietTheDarkAbsol answer describes this)

By separating out the lines you add in a `\n` or new line whereas `else` MUST always come after the closing brace of the opening `if`.

```
<?php if ($a === $b) { ?>  
<?php } ?>  
<?php else { ?>
```

This is interpreted as `if ($a === $b) { \n } \n else {`

The `\n` or new line after the `if`s closing bracket removes any ability for the parser to understand that the else is associated with the `if` and throws the error.

#### An alternative approach to remove a requirement for curly braces.

An approach that is particularly useful when interpolating HTML files with PHP is to use an alternative control structure that removes the need for braces. This will also help you in your current predicament as well as making your code look a little cleaner.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['f'])) : // Colon instead of an '{' ?>
    <?php if($_GET['f']=="message_reçus") : ?>
        <!-- HTML here -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- alternative HTML here -->
    <?php endif; // endif; instead of an '}' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As your code is now non reliant on curly braces your problem vanishes as it is waiting for either an `endif;`, `else :` or `elseif (...) :` block.

Comment: Yes that's great but i need an explanation why it dosen't work above!

Comment: That is explained in the answer by Niet. By separating out the lines you add in a `\n` or new line whereas `else` MUST always come after the closing brace of the opening `if`.